# Moment - Calculate Date From Day Of Week

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

My objective is to calculate a date based on the day of the week I provide Moment.

What I am working with:

```js
var date = moment('2020-01-01');
date.day("Sunday")
date.year(2020)
date.isoWeek(0)
console.log(date.format('ddd DD MMM YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

My expectation is that this would print:
`Sun Jan 05 2020 ...`

Instead I receive:
`Tue Dec 24 2019 ...`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Presuming you run the code on 1 Jan 2020, Sunday shifts it to 29 Dec 2019, 2020 shifts it to Tue 29 Dec 2020, then .isoWeek(0) should set it to Tuesday in the week before the first ISO week of 2020, which is Tue 24 Dec 2019.

Comment: @RobG Ah, thank you. I didn't realize order mattered.

Comment: Date arithmetic is difficult because not only does order matter, but it's often not symmetric so adding a time period then subtracting it doesn't necessarily end up where it started. ;-)